# SQL Server % has more columns than were specified in the column list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   'B' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

I have a stored procedure with the following command:

```
SELECT 
    A.Id,
    A.Description,
    B.StartDate
FROM 
    MyATable A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(MyDate) AS StartDate, A_Id, X_Id, Y_Id
     FROM MyBTable
     WHERE ActionId = 25
     GROUP BY A_Id, X_Id, Y_Id) B ON A.Id = B.A_Id
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Probably because you're grouping by B_Id instead of A_Id in the inner SELECT?

Comment: where are you 'declaring' B? should it not be FROM MyBTable B?

Comment: This type of error wouldn't really occur on this query.  Are you sure this query is an accurate representation of the code in the stored procedure?

Comment: That was not the problem? I have correct this A_Id.

Comment: Are you just running this command? This looks like you are running this from a view.

Answer (score 0):

It's in a stored procedure.

I have created a temporary table (and at the end => drop it)

And then I have inserted the select-statement who was in the inner join

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable (StartDate, A_Id)

INSERT INTO #tempTable (StartDate, A_Id) SELECT MAX(MyDate), A_Id GROUP BY A_Id FROM MyBTable
```

And then change the statement into this:

```
SELECT 
  A.Id,
  A.Description,
  B.StartDate
FROM MyATable A
    INNER JOIN #tempTable B ON A.Id = B.A_Id
```

That's much easier.

Comment: Does this mean you solved your issue? None of this makes any sense. Your original question did not contain the INSERT part which is what caused the error.

Comment: For me, it's solved and it does the same as what I wanted. I have split the statement in two statements.

Comment: Ok I have posted the full query.

Comment: There is still not enough information as your question and answer both still don't contain the problem code. Your answer is in fact a worse solution since you are creating more code.